# Message sorting in Kafka Queue for unordered message

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

We are working on a scenario where messages are getting produced in un-ordered time from source system in Kafka Queue.

We want to sort the message in Kafka queue or want to use any other method so that Kafka consumer can consume time sorted message without affecting much real timeliness.

Just for information we are using Storm-Kafka 0.8 integration, hence if anyhow it can be handled using Storm.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: You may be well served by transactional topologies. They guarantee the transactions get executed exactly once and in order.

Comment: Messages are getting produced in unordered manner. Using trident can I sort message before consuming. I have seen that I can use filter but I havent found sorting option. Please suggest.

Comment: As long as there is some sense in which they can be order, then yes.